# java- framework/library that displays xml in tree structure/ enables auto-completion within an XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am working to create a Java based web app that also has ability to parse XML files.

What I am looking for now is, a java library or framework that allows me to do the following--

(1) Display a tree structure displaying all elements in the XML being currently filled in by the end user.

(2) Offer code completion- I have a list of possible constructs that are permitted in my XML...The library should enable code-completion as a user is typing in the XML.

I would be using the library/framework that does the above, in a java web app - I will be using GWT for the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a web app, my first thought would not be Java; it'd be Javascript.  I'd look at jQuery and its UI plug-in.

You may be using Java in the back end, but a browser solution would be well served by a Javascript/HTML/CSS front end.

If you insist on Java in the browser, you can always write an applet and use Swing JTree.